# ExtJS. Refresh page after Delete

Tags: extjs

I have instance of operation entity. I'd like to execute it after some row was successfully deleted from store (ui has been gotten OK response from server).

**1st Issue.** How determine that row was deleted on server and execute some logic after it. 
There are no callbacks for *store.remove/removeAt*. And it seams (from debugging) that listening '*remove*' event on store is not option.

**2nd Issue.** It's possible just to call execute() on operation instance. But how to get know view and even store about this operation. Because simple operation.execute() does not give any effect except request to back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to 1st issue:

```
store.suspendAutoSync();
    store.removeAt(this.rowIndex);
    this.getView().getStore().sync({
        success:function(){
            ...
        },
        failure:function(){
            ...
        }
    });
```